# Рекурсивная и не рекурсивная с++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Написал код но выводить неправильно в чем проблема?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <locale.h>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;
double* aArrayX; 

// нерекурсивная функция

double Calculate(int N) 
{
    double Summ=0;
    for(int i=1;i<=N;i++)
        Summ+=pow(aArrayX[i],2);
    return Summ;
}

// рекурсивная функция

double CalculateRec(int N)
{
    if (N>=1)
        return pow(aArrayX[N],2)+CalculateRec(N-1);
    else 
        return 0;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"rus");
    int N;
    double fResult;
    cout<<"Input N"<<endl;
    cin>>N;
    if (N>0)
    {
        // применение оператора new для формирования указателя на массив
        aArrayX=new double [N];
        // инициазизация элементов массива
        cout<<"Input x(0):"<<endl;
        cin>>aArrayX[0];
        cout<<"Input x(1):"<<endl;
        cin>>aArrayX[1];
        for(int i=2;i<=N;i++)
            aArrayX[i+1]=pow(aArrayX[i],2) - pow(aArrayX[i-1],2);
        // вызов нерекурсивной функции Calculate
        fResult=Calculate(N);
        cout<<"Result(not recursion)= "<<fResult<<endl;
        // вызов рекурсивной функции CalculateRec
        fResult=CalculateRec(N);
        cout<<"Result(recursion)= "<<fResult<<endl;
        // вывод всех элементов x(i)
        for(int i=0;i<=N;i++)
            cout<<"x("<<i<<")= "<<aArrayX[i]<<endl;
    } 
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Думаю, выводит неправильно потому, что считает неправильно. Или проблема именно в выводе?

Comment: считает не правильно

Comment: Хотфикс: `aArrayX[i+1]=pow(aArrayX[i],2) - pow(aArrayX[i-1],2);` -> `aArrayX[i]=pow(aArrayX[i-1],2) - pow(aArrayX[i-2],2);`. И заменить `new double[N]` на `new double[N+1]`

Comment: Почему в этом коде минус 1 и минус 2? aArrayX[i]=pow(aArrayX[i-1],2) - pow(aArrayX[i-2],2)

Answer (score 1):

Указатель `aArrayX` указывает на массив из `N` элементов, в функции `Calculate` `i` может дойти до этого значения на последней итерации `i<=N`, тем самым выйдя за предел массива, в функции `CalculateRec` выход за предел массива происходит сразу же, в `main` циклы `for` опять же выходит за предел массива. Каждый такой выход - неопределенное поведение Перед разыменованием указателя следует проверять, входит ли индекс в диапазон. Память, выделенная для `aArrayX` утекает. Ну и использовать глобальные переменные не следует. Совсем.

Comment: А чуть по понятнее можно

Comment: @ЛинусТорвальдс "выход за предел массива" - куда уж понятнее? В массиве содержится `N` элементов, индекс последнего будет `N - 1`. Попытка доступа к элементу с индексом, большим, либо равным `N` - неопределенное поведение.

Answer (score 0):

Ну вот как Linux написать, так он тут как тут, а как простенькую программку...

Поскольку ваше решение из серии "зачем просто, если можно сложно?", пишу заново:

```
void Iteration()
{
    double x0 = 0.3, x1 = 0.5;
    double Z = x1*x1;

    for(int n = 1; n <= 7; ++n)
    {
        cout << "n = " << n << " Z = " << setprecision(12) << Z << endl;
        double x = x1*x1-x0*x0;
        Z += x*x;
        x0 = x1;  x1 = x;
    }
}

void Recursion(double x0 = 0.3, double x1 = 0.5, double Z = 0.0, int n = 1)
{
    if (n > 7) return;
    Z += x1*x1;
    cout << "n = " << n << " Z = " << setprecision(12) << Z << endl;
    Recursion(x1,x1*x1-x0*x0,Z,n+1);
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    cout << "Iteration:\n";
    Iteration();
    cout << "Recursion:\n";
    Recursion();
}
```